# Get observations per node in cluster

Tags: matlab, cluster-analysis, linkage

After creating a cluster from some data (using an example of 6 observations), I want to get the observations from each node that the tree holds.

For the given example:

```
Node5 [1,2,3,4,5,6]
Node4 [1,2,3,5,6]
Node3 [2,3,5,6]
```

...and so on

So far I have used this code, with n being the number of observations in linkDist, which is an an agglomerative hierarchical cluster tree:

```
for i=1:n-1
     clusterVals = cluster(linkDist,'maxClust',i);
     k = find(clusterVals==i);
end
```

The problem is that the cluster numeration is changing due to the iterations. For example

```
cluster(linkDist,'maxClust',2) % [2,2,1,2,2,2]
cluster(linkDist,'maxClust',3) % [2,2,3,2,1,2]
```

For the following tree:

[image]

Is there a solution for my problem? 
Thank you very much!

Comment: Do *not* assume cluster numbers to be stable. They are assigned by the algorithm internally, not based on your data. You *need* to align them as necessary for your application.

Comment: Do you have an idea how to accomplish that?